# swift user notifications: why is nextTriggerDate nil?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdatecomponents, usernotifications

When I run the following (on January 7 2017):

```
        let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: TimeZone.current, from: date)
        print("dateComponents = \(dateComponents)")
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching:dateComponents, repeats: false)
        let nextDate = trigger.nextTriggerDate()
        print("nextDate = \(nextDate)")
```

then I get the following output:

> dateComponents = calendar: gregorian (current) timeZone: Europe/Stockholm (current) era: 1 year: 2017 month: 1 day: 8 hour: 21 minute: 34 second: 0 nanosecond: 0 weekday: 1 weekdayOrdinal: 2 quarter: 0 weekOfMonth: 1 weekOfYear: 1 yearForWeekOfYear: 2017 isLeapMonth: false
>
> nextDate = nil

Question: why is `trigger.nextTriggerDate() = nil` ?

**UPDATE:** I had the feeling that my `dateComponents` could be *overdetermined*. I therefore introduced a `nextEvent` that only contained the day hour and minute of the dateComponents:

```
 var nextEvent = DateComponents()
 nextEvent.day = dateComponents.day
 nextEvent.hour = dateComponents.hour
 nextEvent.minute = dateComponents.minute
        
 let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching:nextEvent, repeats: false)
```

when I now invoke `trigger.nextTriggerDate()` it becomes

```
nextDate = Optional(2017-01-08 20:34:00 +0000)
```

as it should. But I do not understand why I cannot use the dateComponents when I create the trigger.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

During my tests I found `dateComponents.quarter = 0` to be the cause of the problems. Zero quarter is obviously wrong, it should be `quarter = 1` It seems there is an old [bug](http://www.openradar.me/16341277) that causes the date components to have an invalid quarter.

If you manually set `dateComponents.quarter = 1` or just `dateComponents.quarter = nil`, everything starts to work.

Comment: I edited out the previous answer because it wasn't very specific. I think I found the real cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, who would think that date components returned from `calendar.dateComponents(in: timeZone, from: date)` are incorrect for local notifications.